# Timelinejs display nothing

Tags: javascript, timeline

I'm using the following code to get timelinejs, which is not working... I am new to this, confused
 with strange behavior!!!! I got this example from tutorial, which is not working for me.. I am doing something wrong but I couldn't figure out where the exact problem is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Timeline demo</title>
            <style>body {font: 10pt arial;}</style>
            <style>.timeline-embed{color: magenta}</style>
            <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>    

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timeline.css">
        </head>

        <body>
        <div id="timeline-embed"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [];

        data.push({
        'start': new Date(2000, 01, 01),
        'end': new Date(2000, 02, 03),  // end is optional
        'content': 'Ram'});

        console.log(data);

        var timeline_config = {
        width:              '100%',
        height:             '600',
        source:             data,
        embed_id:           'timeline-embed',               //OPTIONAL USE A DIFFERENT DIV ID FOR EMBED
        start_at_end:       false,                          //OPTIONAL START AT LATEST DATE
        start_at_slide:     '4',                            //OPTIONAL START AT SPECIFIC SLIDE
        start_zoom_adjust:  '3',                            //OPTIONAL TWEAK THE DEFAULT ZOOM LEVEL
        hash_bookmark:      true,                           //OPTIONAL LOCATION BAR HASHES
        debug:              true,                           //OPTIONAL DEBUG TO CONSOLE
        lang:               'en',                           //OPTIONAL LANGUAGE
        maptype:            'watercolor',                   //OPTIONAL MAP STYLE
        css:                'timeline.css',     //OPTIONAL PATH TO CSS
        js:                 'timeline-min.js'    //OPTIONAL PATH TO JS
        }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="storyjs-embed.js"></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the complied directory structure! I could solved it by replacing the compiled directory of timelinejs!